# change function ajax call from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following code consists of drop-down "(id=name" which populates from "listplace.php" through ajax call which works correctly.

Now I am trying to make another ajax call using the `change function`. when I select the particular item already populated on dropdown box it has to pass the selected item `name1` in `'where'` query to `dataprod.php` and has to display the products by clearing the existing products list available.

I am doubtful over the `$name1` response from `dataprod.php`. Please help!!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {place: '<?= $_GET['place'] ?>'},
        url: 'listplace.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.option.length) {
                var $el = $("#name"); 
                $el.empty(); // remove old options
                for (var i = 0; i < json.option.length; i++) {
                    $el.append($('<option>',
                        {
                            value: json.option[i],
                            text: json.option[i]
                        }));
            }else {
                alert('No data found!');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

ajax 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#name").change(function(){
 var name1 = this.value;
 $.ajax ({
     url: "dataprod.php",
     data: {place: '<?= $_GET['name1'] ?>'},
     success: function (response) {
        $('.products-wrp').html('')
        $('.products-wrp').html(response);     
     }
      }else {
        $('.products-wrp').html('');
  }
}
```

dataprod.php

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");
$name1 = $_POST['name1'];
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code,  
product_image, product_price FROM products_list where product_name='$name1'");

$products_list =  '<ul id ="products_list" class="products-wrp">';
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
</form>
</li>
EOT;
}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';
echo $products_list;
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: oh sure!! I will fix it. But will my second ajax function will run ?

Comment: so what problem are you facing now

Comment: Please explain your problem. Also, there is an extra `}` in your change function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling ajax event on element which is loaded via ajax action so the change event is not bind and nothing is happend.

For ajax 2 action use below code.

```
$(document.body).on('change',"#name",function (e) {
   //doStuff
  var name1 = this.value;
 $.ajax ({
     url: "dataprod.php",
     data: {place: '<?= $_GET['name1'] ?>'},
     success: function (response) {
        $('.products-wrp').html('')
        $('.products-wrp').html(response);     
     }
      }else {
        $('.products-wrp').html('');
  }
}
```